# quarkus mutiny: neo4j type mismatch compilation handling

Tags: neo4j, quarkus, mutiny

This is my code:

```java
@Path("/hello")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class GreetingResource {

    private final Driver driver;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Uni<String> hello() {
        return Multi.createFrom().resource(
            driver::rxSession,
            session -> session.readTransaction(tx -> {
                RxResult result = tx.run("MATCH (f:Fruit) RETURN f.name as name ORDER BY f.name");
                return Multi.createFrom().publisher(result.records()).map(record -> record.get("name").asString());
            })
        ).withFinalizer(session -> {
            return Multi.createFrom().publisher(session.close());
        });
    }

}
```

I'm getting those two compilation messages:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Multi<Object> to Uni<String>
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Multi<Object> to Uni<Void>
```

I don't quite figure since `record.get("name").asString` returns me an `String`...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The finalizer function must return a `Uni<Void>`. In your code, it returns a `Publisher<Object>`. Also, your method is going to return a `Multi` and not a `Uni`.

Try the following approach:

```java
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public Multi<String> hello() {
    return Multi.createFrom().resource(
            driver::rxSession,
            session -> session.readTransaction(tx -> {
                RxResult result = tx.run(
                  "MATCH (f:Fruit) RETURN f.name as name ORDER BY f.name");
                return Multi.createFrom().publisher(result.records())
                   .map(record -> record.get("name").asString());
            })
    ).withFinalizer(session -> {
        return Uni.createFrom().publisher(session.close());
    });
}
```